# Creating a gantt chart with a high volume of hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have created a gantt chart to keep up with a project. Each task has 50 to 100 external files (word, excel, PDF). I need a link to each file in the workbook. Loading each file individually in separate cells or a list box would take hours.

Are there any options to drag and drop several files into a list box or combo box? Or any other way I could import all files at once?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In the folder that has your 50 external files, create a batch file such as:

```
dir/s/b *.doc *.pdf *.xls* > files.txt
```

Run the batch file to get a list of documents. Paste this list into excel. Each line will end up in a different row. Clean up as necessary.

Once all your file names are in a list, and are correct with full paths, select the first cell, and run this macro to make the names links:

```
Sub Macro2()

Do While (Selection.Value <> "")
   Path = Selection.Value
   ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=Path, TextToDisplay:=Path

   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
   Loop
End Sub
```